# Longest non decreasing sequence - n log n?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand the n log n solution. It seems that you dont have to store the entire temp lists at any given point, just the last element would do.

How does that work?

I didnt want to post on the existing posts, so created a new one.

Spent a lot of time understanding it. . :(

Comment: Can you post the solution you are referring to?

Answer (score 4):

> you don't have to store the entire temp lists at any given point, just the last element would do.

First, recall the O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution: you set up an array `L` that has at each element `i` the length of the longest non-decreasing subsequence of `A` ending at element `i`. Here is an example:

```
A: 2 5 7 3 8 2 9 6 9
L: 1 2 3 2 4 2 5 3 6
```

Now imagine setting up an array `M`, which at each index `k` stores the element of `A` that ends the longest non-decreasing subsequence of length `k`. Here is how `M` would look at each step (dash `-` shows places that are not filled in)

```
M (step 0) - - - - - - - - -
M (step 1) 2 - - - - - - - -
M (step 2) 2 5 - - - - - - -
M (step 3) 2 5 7 - - - - - -
M (step 4) 2 3 7 - - - - - -
M (step 5) 2 3 7 8 - - - - -
M (step 6) 2 2 7 8 - - - - -
M (step 7) 2 2 7 8 9 - - - -
M (step 8) 2 2 6 8 9 - - - -
M (step 9) 2 2 6 8 9 9 - - -
```

Work through the example manually to understand the mechanics of filling out the array `M`.

Now comes the key observation: **at each step, `M` is ordered in non-decreasing order**. Intuitively, this is clear, because otherwise the larger number could be attached to a longer sequence, and be moved up the array `M`.

This lets you construct your algorithm:

- Store the last position `maxPos` of `M` that has been filled in
- When you arrive at `A[i]`, run a binary search in `M[0..maxPos]` for a place where `A[i]` should be placed
- If you end up in the middle of the array, replace the old value with `min(A[i], oldValue)`
- If the element is larger than or equal to all elements added to `M` so far, add `A[i]` to the end, and increment `maxPos`

It is easy to see that the above algorithm is O(n*log(n)), because each of its `n` steps uses a binary search, which is log(n).

Comment: Awesome. Just, we don't really need to replace the old value if we end up in the middle of the array, do we?

Comment: @user3923424 You are right, we do not need to always replace the value; only when the replacement is smaller. I edited the answer to use the `min` function to indicate this.